# Driving a Driver with a Hotkey

Tags: modifiers, interface, drivers

Is there a way to access a driver with a hotkey? I am getting tired of selecting a data block in order to drive a driver. I want a quick way to turn on and off many modifiers so I can toggle between high-poly viewing and low-poly real-time animation.

Answer (score 1):

Just create ONE driver for all "show in viewport" or whatever you need and create ONE custom property in the scene which says e.g. Highpoly = False/true. And it that driver enable/disable your show viewport depending on that custom scene property. Copy this driver to all your "show in viewport" or whatever...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I knew how to do this. I was looking for a hotkey or sidebar option to save going to scene properties if I have properties open on something more useful.

Comment: Hey @troy :). Keep in mind you can pin any of your properties tabs to be always visible

Comment: Although you answered part of Troy's question, I am also interested in finding a way to use a keyboard hotkey to toggle a driver on and off.